# build tools 21.1.1 proguard not recognizing `-keep` and rules

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-gradle-plugin, build-tools

`Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ManagedClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection`

despite having `-dontwarn org.apache.**` in my proguard rules file

`Warning:org.joda.time.Weeks: can't find referenced class org.joda.convert.FromString`

despite having `-dontwarn org.joda.**` in my proguard rules file, and `-keep class org.** { *; }` along with `-keep interface org.** { *; }`

`Warning:there were 140 instances of library classes depending on program classes.`

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

so then I look at my app structure

```
 buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
   }
```

`proguard-project.txt` is in the same folder as this build.gradle file in this module.

Not sure what is broken now, I guess there is something else that nobody told me about when I was required to update to Build Tools 21.1.1 to make other things work. any insight appreciated.

Comment: My project with proguard works as expected

Comment: @EugenMartynov thanks thats so helpful , actually it could help me narrow something down I suppose

Comment: Sorry! You're completely right that my comment is useless, Unfortunately can not delete. Sorry again

Comment: @EugenMartynov actually, I copied all my rules to `proguard-rules.pro` since it was now obvious that I needed to change my approach. I get a different error, but my dontwarns and other rules are working now, so thanks for the contribution

Comment: I have next line `proguardFile file( 'proguard-rules.txt' )` and file is in same folder as `build.gradle`

Comment: I use gradle 2.2.1 and 0.14.4 android gradle plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to copy all of my rules into `proguard-rules.pro` which the IDE had previously automatically generated for me, and then proguard worked as expected

I still don't know where getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt') is supposed to be located, but it is not being read, I moved it within my module and in the root folder of the project.